# How to make the method generic to return a List of any type

Tags: java, generics

How to make this method generic to return a `List` of any type currently it returns a `List` of `String`:

```
public static List<String> splitCommaSeparatedStringToListAnyDataTypeArray(String s) {
    List<String> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    if (isNull(s)) {
        return ints;
    }
    String[] split = s.split(COMMA);
    for (String st : split) {
        ints.add(String.valueOf(st));
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Comment: Why did you mark it -1 ? :@

Comment: check now hope it is clear and if it is not clear you don't need to vote it down. you could have only asked.

Comment: It is not me, I guess it is someone that found it not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, you could use a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) to convert a `String` to a given type, you would then rewrite your method as next:

```
public static <T> List<T> splitCommaSeparatedStringToList(String s, 
    Function<String, T> function) {
    if (isNull(s)) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    // Convert the array of String into a List of T
    return Arrays.stream(s.split(COMMA)).map(function).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Your initial method would be the equivalent of `splitCommaSeparatedStringToList(myInputString, String::valueOf)`.

---

For previous version of Java, the logic is the same, simply use [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) from **Google Guava** to replace the `Stream` and use [`com.google.common.base.Function`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html) instead of `java.util.function.Function` as **mapper function**.

```
public static <T> List<T> splitCommaSeparatedStringToList(String s, 
    Function<String, T> function) {
    if (isNull(s)) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return FluentIterable.from(Arrays.asList(s.split(COMMA))).transform(function).toList();
}
```

Comment: I am using using Java 7

Answer (score -1):

only replace `List<String> with List<?>`

```
public static List<?> splitCommaSeparatedStringToListAnyDataTypeArray(String s) {
    List<String> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    if (isNull(s)) {
        return ints;
    }
    String[] split = s.split(COMMA);
    for (String st : split) {
        ints.add(String.valueOf(st));
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Comment: It's not helpful to return a wildcard type.